# Как очистить память, выделенную под элементы связного списка?

Tags: c++

У меня есть связный список из 4 элементов. Я в начале программы выделяю память помощью оператора `new` для одного элемента списка и затем еще для трех в цикле.

Как мне теперь правильно очистить всю выделенную память? Как я понимаю этого недостаточно: `delete first;`

Пытаюсь использовать delete в цикле, но программа выдает ошибку компиляции:

*Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00B76EFA в CPPConsoleApp.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00008127*

```
struct node
{
    int item;
    node *next;

    node(int x, node *t)
    {
        item = x;
        next = t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    node *first = new node(1, NULL);
    node *last = first;

    for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
        last = (last->next = new node(i, last->next));

    for (node *current = first; current != 0; current = current->next)
        cout << current->item << " ";

    // Здесь ошибка
    for (node *current = first; current != 0; current = current->next)
        delete current;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, уж. Обращаться к уже удаленной памяти не самая лучшая идея (ее содержимое может измениться при удалении).

Что-то в таком духе

```
for (node *t, *current = first; current && t = current->next; current = t)
   delete current;
```

(не проверял, но думаю, идея ясна).

Answer (score 2):

Самый просто способ - это добавить деструктор в класс `node`. Например

```
struct node
{
    int item;
    node *next;

    node(int x, node *t)
    {
        item = x;
        next = t;
    }

    ~node() { delete next; }
};
```

А в функции `main` запишите

```
delete first;
```

Другой подход - это использовать цикл

```
while ( first )
{
    node *tmp = first;
    first = first->next;
    delete tmp;
}
```

Comment: Только в деструкторе надо проверять указатель next на null. Но опять же, что будет, если связный список кольцевой? Тогда указатель next последнего элемента будет указывать на первый элемент, который уже удалён.

Comment: @maestro Не надо проверять указатель на null. Если список кольцевой, то это вы должны написать соответствующий код для удаления элементов, который будет учитывать эту специфику.

Comment: Простой способ ведет к stack overflow.

Comment: @Arkady Это хороший учебный пример рекурсии для простых списков, которые содержат небольшое количество элементов. При этом компилятор может использовать хвостовую рекурсию, которая не приводит ни к какому переполнению стека.